# Method got terminated before return a value how to handle this exception?

Tags: java, exception

As per the below program I want to do some operation based upon each labels; from list of the labels.

File1.java perform based upon function1() return value as well as File2.java from function2() return value and File3.java from function3() return value.

**For example:**

Label list have 5 Labels**. While parsing

Label1 - success

Label2 – success

Label3 – got failed in function3() in File4.java , and execution stopped.

Label4 and 5 not executed.

---

My problem is File4.java, function3() before return a value got terminated due to some issue. I want to continue the execution Label4 and 5 after label 3 got crashed.

I want to know how to handle this issue in inside the File1.java, please help me is there any exception method available** or give me some other method or  idea to solve this issue.

Thank you in advance

**File1.java**

```
File2 file2 = new File2();    
for(String label: listOfLabels) {
    var1 = file2.function1(label);
    statements;
}
```

**File2.java**

```
File3 file3 = new File3();
Public int function1(LabelType label){
    var2 = file3.function2();
    statements;
    return var2;
}
```

**File3.java**

```
File4 file4 = new File4();
Public int function2(){
    var3 =  file4.function3();
    statements;
    Return var3;
}
```

**File4.java**

```
Public int function3(){
    Statements;
    //Before return a value execution terminated, because of some label values
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try-catch the exception inside your loop in File1.java as follows:

```
for(String label: listOfLabels) {
    try {    
        var1 = file2.function1(label);
        statements;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error encountered for: " + label);  
    }
}
```